# iPhone library for starting/stopping app's services?

Tags: iphone

I've worked on several iPhone applications which all require some subset of the same services: RemoteIO audio, GPS, push notifications, face sensor activation, idle timeout disabling, etc, etc. The application delegate callback methods become bloated with all of this initialization code which is slightly different in each app.

So my question is: is there a library for handling all this? Some system that lets me say, "this app uses services A, B, and C, and they should launch in this order"? The services would be defined so that they'll automatically get the application lifecycle callbacks they need, like the application going into the background, audio interruptions, etc.

This is pretty ill-defined, which is why I'm hesitant to write this code yet. If someone else has solved the problem then I can avoid duplicating all of the mistakes they made on their approach to a solution.

Comment: Yes a library like this would be very helpful

Comment: You said yourself that *"The application delegate callback methods become bloated with all of this initialization code which is slightly different in each app."* - how would having a library reduce what you have to do in regards to the bits that are "different in each app"?

Comment: Different applications launch different services, so while the initialize-gps block is the same across the apps, where it occurs is different depending on how important GPS activity is to that application.

Answer (score 0):

The only one i could think of would be three20, but not sure if that isn't a bit too much.  ( check http://api.three20.info/annotated.php)

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I skimmed the class list but nothing relevant stuck out.